# Unable to save content title

Tags: nodes, feeds

I am using feeds to import content to my custom content type, Clients.

After the Import, the mapping comes up fine, the Content Title displays in the Page View Node, however, when I go to edit the content, the Title comes empty & also does not save the updated title.

It was working fine a few days back. I haven't made any changes or updates to any modules.

Please advice.

Thanks

Comment: First thing you need to look at is the related watchdog entries, during the "Save node" action, to see if there is some error reported. If you see sth relevant, please update your question.

Comment: Does this happen to all the other content types? If you happen to have only one then, for testing purposes, create another one and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, did as directed, is happening only to one content type. Created a similar content type, works fine. How do I identify the cause for this issue to ensure this doesnt happen again? Thank

Answer (score 0):

I've had something similar happen to me before. Turned out that Automatic Entity Label module was overwriting the title field with an empty token.

Comment: Hi, @Stefanos, No there are no errors reported while saving or updating the node.

Comment: Hi Thank you for the suggestion, @Garette, No I do not have Automatic Entity Label Module installed. Any other suggestions I could try? Thanks